# How to forget sftp password in Nautilus (none in seahorse)

Tags: nautilus, ssh, password, seahorse

I added the entry `sftp://daniel@<somedomain>` to my bookmarks in Nautilus. The first time it was accessed it asked for the password but never after that. I cannot remember which option I selected to remember (e.g. until end of session).

In any case, I want Nautilus to forget the access password and ask me every time I open the remote file system. Unmounting did not cause it to forget the password. I've also opened `seahorse` and this key is not there.

Any idea where the key is stored and how can I force nautilus to forget the password?

Comment: "Try deleting the bookmark. Then create it again." -- This didn't work.

Comment: "Did you check for ssh password in seahorse?" -- There is only one entry there and it is for something else. Since the password is supposed to be remember until the end of the session, perhaps it is stored in memory but that's just guessing.

Comment: Sorry, I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 5):

I did the same thing as you and was also surprised not to find the key in `seahorse`.
The only way I found to make Nautilus forget the pwd was to close my session. Then nautilus asked me the password again, with the same 3 options, and I selected the 1st one.

1. Forget the password
2. Remember until end of session
3. Remember forever

I think it only stores the password in `seahorse` when you select the 3rd option.
For the 2nd option, it must store it in a temporary place that I don't know about.
For the 1st option, it doesn't store it at all.

Comment: With option 2 I found that restarting nautilus or gnome didn't work, but rebooting did

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 16.04, this solved the issue:

1. Click "Search your computer" (top left corner)
2. Type *Passwords and Keys*
3. Under Passwords - Login, you can right click and delete the saved password

Reference: jamesisin's answer in this [post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1387375)

Hope that helps!

Comment: As stated in another answer, this only works if you have selected "remember forever" (the "passwords and keys" app is `seahorse`).

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 18.04, this solved the issue:

1. Click on the apps icon (bottom left corner)
2. Search on search-bar `Passwords and Keys`
3. Click on it
4. Right-click on the key you wish to remove under `Login` tab and press `Delete`

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/1043437/1171332

Answer (score -1):

run *seahorse* from the bash:

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/23350/where-to-find-nautilus-password-storage-for-shares/?answer=23351#post-id-23351
//for 30 character answer...

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Answer that a purely link based are of low quality. Please provide more details.